# Upgrading a Handler with Runnable to lambda expression

Tags: java, android, lambda, java-8

I want to upgrade this code to use a lambda expression:

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        missileX = ufoX;
        resetRecent();
        waitForUfoTimer = false;
    }
}, randomize(20000, 18000));
```

I try it this way but it doesn't compile:

```
Handler handler2 = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler2.postDelayed(Runnable task = () -> {  
    missileX = ufoX;
    resetRecent();
    waitForUfoTimer = false; 
  }
}, randomize(20000, 18000));
```

Where are some instructions so that I can learn how to do it? It is preposterous that I must guess the syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to declare a variable to assign to the lambda. This is enough :

```
Handler handler2 = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
handler2.postDelayed(() -> {  
    missileX = ufoX;
    resetRecent();
    waitForUfoTimer = false; 
  }
, randomize(20000, 18000));
```

Comment: But that does not compile in Android Studio with Java 8. I get error message "return type required" and 2 more error messages.

Comment: Probably an undesirable coma.

Comment: The following compiles though: `handler2.postDelayed(
                () -> {
                    missileX = ufoX;
                    resetRecent();
                    waitForUfoTimer = false;
                }            
                
    , randomize(20000, 18000));`

Comment: Now it compiles. I must've had some junk character in between.